# How to add new Column in Python pandas dataframe by searching keyword value given in list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list-comprehension

I want to add new Column in the dataframe on the basis of Identified keyword:

This is Current Data(Dataframe name = df):

```
    Topic                   Count
0   This is Python          39
1   This is SQL             6
2   This is Paython Pandas  98
3   import tkinter          81
4   Learning Python         94
5   SQL Working             85
6   Pandas and Work         67
7   This is Pandas          30
8   Computer                20
9   Mobile Work             55
10  Smart Mobile            69
```

My desired output as below

```
    Topic                   Count       Groups
0   This is Python          39          Python_Group
1   This is SQL             6           SQL_Group
2   This is Paython Pandas  98          Python_Group
3   import tkinter          81          Python_Group
4   Learning Python         94          Python_Group
5   SQL Working             85          SQL_Group
6   Pandas and Work         67          Python_Group
7   This is Pandas          30          Python_Group
8   Computer                20          Devices_Group
9   Mobile Work             55          Devices_Group
10  Smart Mobile            69          Devices_Group
```

**How to Identify `Groups` Column Value**

The Groups created on the basis of below Identity in `Topics` Column.
if particular word found in `Topics` then particular group name need assign to it

**List of Keywords from `Topic` Column**

```
Python_Group = ['Python','Pandas','tkinter']
SQL_Group = ['SQL', 'Select']
Devices_Group = ['Computer','Mobile']
```

I have tried below code for it:

```
df['Groups'] = [
    'Python Group' if "Python" in x 
    else 'Python Group' if "Pandas" in x
    else 'Python Group' if "tkinter" in x
    else 'SQL Group' if "SQL" in x
    else 'Devices Group' if "Computer" in x
    else 'Devices Group' if "Mobile" in x
    else '000' 
    for x in df['Topic']]
print(df)
```

Above code is also giving me the desired output but I want to make it more short and quick because in above mentioned dataframe has almost 2MM+ Records and its very difficult for me to write 1k+ line of code to define grouping.

Is there any way where I can utilized **List of keyword** falling under `Topic` Column?
**OR**
any Custom Function that can help me in this iterative process?

**Code:2** Another below code tried after consulting Stack overflow Experts:

```
d = pd.read_excel('Map.xlsx').to_dict('list')
keyword_groups = {x:k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(keyword_groups))   #This line is giving an error
df['Groups'] = (df['Topic'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
               .map(keyword_groups)
               .fillna('000'))
```

**The Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-543675c0b403> in <module>
      3 
      4 keyword_groups = {x:k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
----> 5 pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(keyword_groups))
      6 pat

TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, float found
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to consider maintaining your groups and keywords in a `dict`:

```
d = {'Python_Group': ['Python','Pandas','tkinter'],
     'SQL_Group': ['SQL', 'Select'],
     'Devices_Group': ['Computer','Mobile']}
```

From here, you could easily reverse this to a "keyword: Group" `dict`.

```
keyword_groups = {x:k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}

# {'Python': 'Python_Group',
#  'Pandas': 'Python_Group',
#  'tkinter': 'Python_Group',
#  'SQL': 'SQL_Group',
#  'Select': 'SQL_Group',
#  'Computer': 'Devices_Group',
#  'Mobile': 'Devices_Group'}
```

Then you can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to find these keywords using regex and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) them to the correct group. Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to catch any non-matching groups.

```
pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(keyword_groups))

df['Groups'] = (df['Topic'].str.extract(pat, expand=False)
               .map(keyword_groups)
               .fillna('000'))
```

[out]

```
                     Topic  Count          Groups
0           This is Python     39    Python_Group
1              This is SQL      6       SQL_Group
2   This is Paython Pandas     98    Python_Group
3           import tkinter     81    Python_Group
4          Learning Python     94    Python_Group
5              SQL Working     85       SQL_Group
6          Pandas and Work     67    Python_Group
7           This is Pandas     30    Python_Group
8                 Computer     20   Devices_Group
9              Mobile Work     55   Devices_Group
10            Smart Mobile     69   Devices_Group
```

Comment: The Code is Working fine as you have mentioned but when I am trying to create Variable "d" through import excel file. it is giving me this error `TypeError: sequence item 5: expected str instance, float found`. This is error is coming at time of executing `pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(keyword_groups))` statement. I am trying to load This file, [link](https://www116.zippyshare.com/v/v6bKQCD4/file.html)

Comment: Can you add the code your using to create d from importing from Excel? Just update and add it to your original question. Also that link is not working for me, so I can't see the file.

Comment: @Chis A, I have updated the code at lower part of question, Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you run `print(pd.read_excel('Map.xlxs').head().to_dict())` and print the output for me here please?

Comment: Looks like it could be that one of more of your keys in `keyword_groups` is a float, and not a string. Try replace the `pat = ...` line with `pat = '({})'.format('|'.join([f'{x}' for x in keyword_groups]))` ?

Comment: Thanks for your Support its Working fine

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).  np.select receives 3 parameters, one of conditions, one of results and the last the default value when no condition is found.

```
Python_Group = ['Python','Pandas','tkinter']
SQL_Group = ['SQL', 'Select']
Devices_Group = ['Computer','Mobile']

conditions = [
    df['Topic'].str.contains('|'.join(Python_Group))
    ,df['Topic'].str.contains('|'.join(SQL_Group))
    ,df['Topic'].str.contains('|'.join(Devices_Group))
]

results = [
    "Python_Group"
    ,"SQL_Group"
    ,"Devices_Group"
]

df['Groups'] = np.select(conditions, results, '000')
#output:
    Topic                   Count   Groups
0   This is Python          39      Python_Group
1   This is SQL             6       SQL_Group
2   This is Paython Pandas  98      Python_Group
3   import tkinter          81      Python_Group
4   Learning Python         94      Python_Group
5   SQL Working             85      SQL_Group
6   Pandas and Work         67      Python_Group
7   This is Pandas          30      Python_Group
8   Computer                20      Devices_Group
9   Mobile Work             55      Devices_Group
10  Smart Mobile            69      Devices_Group
```